# Pandas - find row by column value (id) and update its values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for an efficient way to update one ow in Pandas Dataframe (like in DB).

There is an `id` column with unique values (ids)

```
contacts = 

   id  ... phone          email
0  33  ... +4219999999    WORK:pete@zzz.de
1  45  ... +4215444444    HOME:rot@zzz.de
2  20  ... +4213333333    WORK:aon@zzz.de
3  11  ... +4215553454    WORK:lev@zzz.de
```

I want to update row with `id` == 45 by a dict `{'phone'='+4511111111','email':'freddy@gg.com'}`

Basically, I want to replace it with data from a given dictionary.

This way I can get the row:

```
contact = contacts.query(f'internal_id == "45"')
```

How to modify the dataframe so all the values of the row change?

Comment: `df.loc[df.id == 45, df.columns.difference(["id"])] = pd.DataFrame(d, index=[(df.id == 45).idxmax()])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `set_index` with `'id'` and update the relevant row with a dictionary by passing it to a Series:

```
df = df.set_index('id')
df.loc[45] = pd.Series(d)
```

Output:

```
          phone             email
id                               
33   4219999999  WORK:pete@zzz.de
45  +4511111111     freddy@gg.com
20   4213333333   WORK:aon@zzz.de
11   4215553454   WORK:lev@zzz.de
```